# Why did the two prompts in this program to receive input show on the same line?

Tags: c, gcc, input

I have a problem when getting input from the user. I used the `scanf` function to get the input from the user, which I think is the cause of the problem.

I want the two prompts to be on separate lines.

The following code is a simple example of the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char name[20];
    int age = 0;
    int index;

    printf("1- Insert a new student.\n");
    printf("2- Delete a student.\n");
    printf("3- Show all students.\n");
    printf("4- Exit.\n\nChoose: ");
    scanf("%d", &index);

    printf("Enter your name: ");
    scanf("%20[^\n]s", name);
    //fgets(name, 20, stdin); // <--- Does the same thing.

    printf("Enter your age: ");
    scanf("%d", &age);

    printf("Name: %s, Age: %d\n", name, age);
    return 0;
}
```

The result as text:

```
1- Insert a new student.
2- Delete a student.
3- Show all students.
4- Exit.

Choose: 2
Enter your name: Enter your age:
```

An image:

[image]

**Why did the two prompts show on the same line?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you change this:

```
scanf("%20[^\n]s", name);
```

to this:

```
scanf(" %19[^\n]", name);
```

for these reasons:

- The buffer size you specify to `scanf` does not include the final `NUL` terminator (unlike with `fgets`).
- The previous `scanf` left a newline in the input buffer, and the format specifiers `%[]` and `%c` do not automatically filter it (unlike `%d` and other specifiers). Adding the space tells `scanf` to filter it.
- The final `s` is not part of the format `%[]` but is a frequent mistake by coders who have used `%s`.

Note too, that `scanf` with `%[]` is not equivalent to `fgets()`, which reads any final newline and places it in the buffer supplied.

Comment: Regarding `fgets` It does the same problem, How to use it without cause that problem?

Comment: I did not suggest using `fgets` but the answer is by not mixing your input methods. if you use `fgets` use it for every input, and then apply `sscanf` to the input string to extract its data. It's actually easier doing this, to recover from an invalid input (such as a alphabetic data entered for a number).

Answer (score 3):

As the other comments advise, you are better off using `%19[^\n]`. However, doing that will still cause your issue. This should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

int age = 0;
int index;
char name[20];

printf("1- Insert a new student.\n");
printf("2- Delete a student.\n");
printf("3- Show all students.\n");
printf("4- Exit.\n\nChoose: ");
scanf("%d", &index);

printf("Enter your name: ");
scanf(" %19[^\n]", name);


printf("Enter your age: ");
scanf("%d", &age);

printf("Name: %s, Age: %d\n", name, age);
  return 0;
}
```

Note the leading white space added in the scanf function. The leading space is to  consume any trailing character in the stdin that might have been left by previous user input.

```
Program output
 clang-7 -pthread -lm -o main main.c
 ./main
1- Insert a new student.
2- Delete a student.
3- Show all students.
4- Exit.

Choose: 1
Enter your name: jimm
Enter your age: 12
Name: jimm, Age: 12
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that should do the trick. Please see the comments contained in the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

  int age = 0;
  int index;
  char name[20];
  int ignore; // Not char as EOF is -1

  // Keep repeating the menu until a valid input
  do {
    printf("1- Insert a new student.\n");
    printf("2- Delete a student.\n");
    printf("3- Show all students.\n");
    printf("4- Exit.\n\nChoose: ");
  while (scanf("%d", &index) != 1 || index < 1 || index > 4); // Check for a valid index

  if (index == 1) { // Choice 1 chosen (maybe switch would be better?

    printf("Enter your name: ");
    fflush(stdout); // So it goes to the terminal
    scanf(" %19[^\n]", name);

    while (1) {
      printf("Enter your age: ");
      fflush(stdout); // So it goes to the terminal
      if (scanf(" %d", &age) == 1 && age > 0) { // I.e. valid age has been read
        break; // We are done with this loop
      }
      // Consume up to end of line
      do {
        ignore == fgetc(stdin);
        if (ignore == EOF) { // Nothing more to be read - error as no age entered
          return -1;
        }
      } while (ignore != '\n');
    }
    printf("Name: %s, Age: %d\n", name, age);
    // Do not need fflush as printf contains \n at the end
    return 0;
  }
    // ... for the other options
}
```